# DIVs not Displaying as Block on Mobile

Tags: css, mobile, block, display

I am making a practice layout (http://commission.lillykauffman.com/itfts.php) and even though everything looks good on desktop, the top elements are not displaying as "block" in mobile.  Since I have no specific code for mobile, it should be the same as on desktop, in theory.

Feel free to look at my code - it's all on the same page - and let me know how I can go about fixing this.  FYI I also did *width:100%* and that doesn't work, and also isn't preferable for my layout.

[Click here for screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDXmT.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your have some stuff on your page that is wider than most mobile view-ports (e.g `#content`, that has a set width of 600px), and therefor extending wider. your problem is not that the divs won't display as blocks, but that some of your blocks are wider than the view-port.

Comment: Also, your main heading is an image and therefore can't have line-brakes, so when the image gets wider than the view-port, the same things as previously mentioned happens.

Comment: Thank you!  I changed everything to percentages but now it's not being reflected on mobile, and neither is a change in font size.  I am using the same coding I usually use for mobile devices and it's not working.  I am quite confused as to why these changes are not being reflected.

Comment: @Lilly You have a lot of stuff that is going on on your site, e.g your floats ain't cleared (some read up https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/). And on second hand, i think your layout should use flex-box instead (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), a lot easier to work with. And again, I would advice against using an image as main heading as you cant line-brake an image.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I was able to incorporate flex and will look into it further.  What happened was my viewport was set to "700" and my code only reflected pixels 500 and under, and now I've gotten it to work.  Thanks again for everyone's help!